# View image through JSON data in express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, react-native, express

I'm trying to view dynamic image from local location in my computer using JSON from backend in express.js

I cant figure it out, why my image doesn't show in my phone
This my backend code

```
app.post('/jenisbudayabatak', (req, res) => {
  const info = `SELECT id_jenis, nm_jenis, gambar FROM jenisbudaya`
  con.query(info, function(err, result){

    if(err){
      return res.status(404).send({
        message: "Terjadi kesalahan, coba lagi nanti"
      })
    }
    const final = []
    const request = "require('./uploads/"
    for (var i = 0 ; i < result.length; i++){
        const getdata = {
          id_jenis: result[i].id_jenis,
          nm_jenis: result[i].nm_jenis,
          gambar: request + result[i].gambar + "')"
        }
      final.push(getdata)
    }
      res.status(200).send({
        data: final
      })
  })
})
```

**My JSON data**

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id_jenis": 2,
            "nm_jenis": "Batak Toba",
            "gambar": "require('./uploads/bataktoba.png')"
        },
        {
            "id_jenis": 3,
            "nm_jenis": "Batak Simalungun",
            "gambar": "require('./uploads/budayasimalungun.jpeg')"
        }
    ]
}
```

**This is how I fetch my value**

```
componentDidMount(){
    fetch('http://192.168.207.161:3000/jenisbudayabatak', { 
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((responseData) => {
        this.setState({
        loading: false,
        datas: responseData.data
        })
    })
    .catch(error=>console.log(error))
}
```

**Render the image**

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.card} onPress={() => {this.clickEventListener(item)}}>
  <Image style={styles.cardImage} source={item.gambar}/>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Can anyone please tell me which I do wrong?

I'm trying to show the image dynamically

Comment: require won't work, make an express endpoint which serves the images

Comment: `"require('./uploads/budayasimalungun.jpeg')"` is not a URL. You need to use a URL.

Comment: Please change your URL. "require" only use for local image path.